# Как сделать сортировку массива простым перебором?

Tags: массивы, php, сортировка

Подскажите, как сделать "сортировку массива простым перебором".
Суть такова: надо реализовать сортировку массива по возрастанию (убыванию) простым (прямым) выбором, используя визуальные компоненты для ввода искомых данных (элементов массива), управления вычислениями (командную кнопку) с отображением результатов (отсортированного массива).

Подскажите, как такое сделать. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 4):

```
$old_array = array(3,4,1,5,3);//массив, который надо отсортировать.
$new_array = array();//отсортированный результат.

for($i=0;$i<count($old_array);$i++){//перебираем количество элементов.
  $lowest = 100500;// очень большое число. Лучше взять вообще MAX_INT
  foreach($old_array as $key=>$value){// ищем локальный минимум.
    if($value<=$lowest){
      $lowest = $value;
      $lowest_key = $key;//запоминаем ключ минимума
    }
  }
  $new_array[$i] = $old_array[$lowest_key];
  unset($old_array[$lowest_key]);//удаляем значение из исходного массива, чтобы больше не натыкаться. Экономим, тем самым время перебора и оставляем возможность поиска одинаковых по значению элементов.
}
```

а вам, собственно, зачем?!

юзайте sort, usort, а?

Comment: а как его на экран вывести?

Comment: print_r($new_array);